# Xcode Import Localizations failed

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

We use the 'Export Localizations...' and 'Import Localizations...' tool of Xcode for localization in our project and it works well on Xcode 12.4. But after we upgrade Xcode to 12.5.0, errors raised with the same 'xliff' file, with message:`Localizable.strings: Missing ';' on line 1028, Check the strings file with plutil or/and check_strings and fix the syntax error.`
We do something below:

1. check all string files `find ./ -name '*.strings' -exec plutil -lint {} \;` but no errors found
2. run command line tool `xcodebuild -importLocalizations -localizationPath xxx.xliff -project  Project.xcodeproj`, and we find some error like this `genstrings: error: bad entry in file .../xxx.m (line = 603): Argument is not a literal string.`, so we fix all the error raised by `NSLocalizedString` and `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`.

but the import is still not working with error `2021-08-05 09:36:17.801 xcodebuild[29848:4770072] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 1028. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug. xcodebuild: error: Localizable.strings: Missing ';' on line 1028` 
If anyone can shed a light it would be wonderful.

Comment: Or does anyone know where the tmp 'Localizable.strings' file is, so I can check it out.

Comment: I finally locate the tmp Localizable.strings file with 'ps aux | grep genstrings' during the cmd 'xcodebuild -importLocalizations -localizationPath xxx.xliff -project  Project.xcodeproj', the output is like below:

Comment: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/genstrings -f /var/folders/0c/csmbvrp5335f7dffhkr19q3m0000gn/T/IDELocalization/11491C26-8514-49C1-AB39-16959FA30825/xx/xx-xx|||||1D6058900D05DD3D006BFB54|||||/xx.xcodeproj/Sources/en.lproj/arguments.plist -o /var/folders/0c/csmbvrp5335f7dffhkr19q3m0000gn/T/IDELocalization/11491C26-8514-49C1-AB39-16959FA30825/xx/xx-xx|||||1D6058900D05DD3D006BFB54|||||/xx.xcodeproj/Sources/en.lproj -d -SwiftUI",

Comment: here you can check 'line 1028' for error. There is a line feed in my case.